# Using postgres.app with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgres.app

I recently re-installed postgres using postgres.app and now my rails app is not able to find the database.  I am getting the following error:

```
dlopen(/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/username/.rvm/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
```

It seems like this problem stems from the fact that I ran

```
brew uninstall postgresql
```

before installing postgres.app.  I was wondering how to tell my already existing rails app to find the database.  Thanks

EDIT:

here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
     adapter: postgresql
     encoding: unicode
     database: *********
     pool: 5
     host: localhost
```

And also, postgres.app is running, the elephant is hanging out.

Comment: Can you please paste your database.yml file and confirm that postgres.app is running?  On a Mac, there will be a black elephant in the top right of the screen when postgres.app is running.  Check the port that postgres.app is running on by clicking the black elephant.

Comment: Have you rebuilt the pg gem?